# How many ways are there to put 4 distinguishable balls into 2 indistinguishable boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

I do not know the answer! How do you do this type of question? Please type the answer and show me the steps to solve it! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these small problems, you can approach directly via brute force or smart counting.

Let our balls be labeled $A,B,C,D$.

We know that ball $A$ will be in *some* box... but we don't care which box it is since we can't tell them apart.  Now that ball $A$ is *in* that box however, we can now tell the two boxes apart.  The box *with* $A$ in it, and the box *without* $A$ in it.

For each of the balls $B,C,D$, choose whether they go in the box *with* $A$ or into the box *without* $A$.  Application of the rule of product/multiplication principle tells us then that there are $2\times 2\times 2 = 8$ such outcomes.

---

For the more general problem of having $n$ distinguishable balls and $k$ indistinguishable boxes, this will rely on [stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\r\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$ counts the number of ways to partition $n$ distinguishable objects into $r$ otherwise indistinguishable non-empty sets.  Assuming you allow some boxes to be empty, we get as a result by summing over all possible number of non-empty boxes a total of:

$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^k\left\{\begin{matrix}n\\r\end{matrix}\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Ball $1$ has $2$ options, ball $2$ has $2$ options, $\dots$

This will give us how many total options? Note that some of these options are actually the same, since our boxes are *indistinguishable*, so we will need to figure out how much we are over-counting by.

---

Another way to look at it is this way: think of it as pairing the numbers $1,2,3,4$ together. How many ways can we pair up all of them together? How many ways can we pair them up so that we have $3$ numbers in one group and a lone number by itself? Then how many ways can we pair them up with $2$ in one group and $2$ in the other?